# AWS EventBridge on-the-fly filter update

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, aws-event-bridge

I want to use the EventBridge filter to control data processing enabled by subscription. For example, I have say 5 customers: A-E. Only B and D have a subscription so I want to only process event payloads coming from customers B and D.

If the subscriber list changes, say by adding customer E, I need to update the EB filter so it is filtering for B, D, & E.

What's the best way to do that on-the-fly so that a subscriber change event triggers a change in the EB filter?

Comment: I guess a meta-question is, what the best way to update a CDK stack on-the-fly?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419909/is-a-question-asking-for-good-ways-to-do-something-really-opinion-based

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the EventBridge configuration on-the-fly you need to execute a CLI command similar to this:

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name mystack...
```

The rest of the command concerns the specific configuration element you want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Note that due to eventual consistency rule changes do not propagate/take effect immediately.